# Hibernate 4.2 SessionFactory in a Synchronized method

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I'm working with Hibernate 4.2.21, In several post's I was watching that the some people use Synchronized in the method to create the Session Factory of Hibernate, my questions is about what is the best practice, with or without? From my side I think if we defined the Variable like static, Synchronized have not sense..

```
public class HibernateSessionFactory {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(HibernateSessionFactory.class);

    private HibernateSessionFactory() {}

    private static synchronized SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        SessionFactory sf = null;

        try {

            configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");


            configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", System.getProperty("myApp.db.dialect"));
            configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", System.getProperty("myApp.db.driver"));
            configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.datasource", System.getProperty("myApp.db.jndi"));

            if (sessionFactory == null) {
                ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
                sf = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
            }

            return sf;

        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            logger.error("Init SessionFactory creation failed: ", ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdownSessionFactory() {

      if(!sessionFactory.isClosed()){
        sessionFactory.close();
        logger.info("Session Factory shutdown");
      }else{
        logger.info("Session Factory is already closed");
      }

    }

}
```

Comment: Looks strange _if (sessionFactory == null)_

Comment: @v.ladynev I thought about it a bit more, and yep.. you are right, it's strange I will deleted, what do you think about my question with synchronized?

Comment: You are right, of course. A class loader do such synchronization itself. But let's wait for a more deep answer :)